# Haskell Church Numerals with custom types

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to solve a Church numerals parser I have a custom type which distinguishes between variable, lambda and application

```
type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term
  deriving Show
```

I have a function called `church`
I can define a cases manually for different variations of church. So let's say:

- `church 0` `Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (Variable  "x"))`
- `church 1` should output `Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (Apply (Variable "f") (Variable "x")))`
- `church 2` should output `Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (Apply (Variable "f") (Apply (Variable "f") (Variable "x"))))`

and so on.

I've tried recursively call the church function as per:

```
church :: Int -> Term
church 0 = Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (Variable  "x"))
church i = Apply (church(i -1)) (Apply (Variable "f") (Variable "x"))
```

However that keeps repeating also the part with `Lambda "f" (Lambda "x"`

The other approach I've tried was

```
church :: Int -> Term
church 0 = Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (Variable  "x"))
church i = Apply (church (i -1)) (Apply (Variable "f") (Variable "x"))
```

However this also yields result with copied lambdas. Am I missing something here? How can I only repeat the application part `(Apply (Variable "f") (Variable "x"))`

Comment: The spacing of the first code fragment does not look right, it renders as `church0` and `churchi`.

Comment: Good spot. Updated the OT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All church numerals start with an `\f -> (\i -> …)`, so that means that our function should look like:

```
church :: Int -> Term
church n = Lambda f (Lambda x (go n))
```

where we still need to implement `go :: Int -> Term`. This thus means that for `go` we have to find a function that looks like:

```
go 0 = Variable "x"
go 1 = Apply (Variable ("f")) (Variable "x")
go 2 = Apply (Variable "x") (Apply (Variable ("f")) (Variable "x"))
```

so for a `go n`, we thus have to return a `Variable "x"` wrapped in *n* items with `Apply (Variable "x")`

The implementation thus should look like:

```
go :: Int -> Term
go 0 = Variable "x"
go n = … (go (n-1))
```

Where I leave implementing `…` as an exercise.